# Convert dataset<Row> to integer in spark with java

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-spark

I have a `dataset<Row>` in spark using java like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Zntn.png)

How can i convert this dataset to integer. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

int x = dataset.first().getInt(0);

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have an error with your code. The error is : java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.DenseVector cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

Comment: I forgot to cast double type into integer before your code. Now the problem is solved. Thank u a lot

Comment: I make casting with : `Dataset<Row> v_pred = predictions.selectExpr("cast(prediction as int) prediction");`